# Oop data structure advice

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures, ooad

I am writing a log file decoder which should be capable of reading many different structures of files. My question is how best to represent this data. I am using C#, but am new to OOP.

An example:
The log files have a range of sensor values. One sensor reading can be called **A**, another **B**. Obviously, there are many more than 2 entry types.
In different log files, they could be stored either as ABABABABAB or AAAAABBBBB.

I was thinking of describing this as blocks of entries. So in the first case, a block would be 'AB', with 5 blocks. In the second case, the first block is 'A', read 5 times. This is followed by a block of 'B', read 5 times.

This is quite a simplification (there are actually 40 different types of log file, each with up to 40 sensor values in a block). No log has more than 300 blocks.

At the moment, I store all of this in a datatable. I have a column for each entry, with a property of how many to read. If this is set to -1, it continues to the next column in the block. If not, it will assume that it has reached the end of the block.

This all seems quite clumsy. Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: Should it be easy readable for users?

Comment: The log file is in binary format. I need to read it in and display it in the GUI. It needs to be clear in the GUI, so I have tried using a DataGridView so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very basic and straightforward:

1. Define an interface for `IEnrty` with properties like `string EntryBlock, int Count`
2. Define a class which represents an `Entry` and implements `IEntry`
3. Code which doing a binary serialization should be aware of interfaces, for instance it should reffer `IEnumerable<IEntry>`
4. Class `Entry` could override `ToString()` to return something like [ABAB-2], surely if this is would be helpful whilst serialization
5. Interface `IEntry` could provide method void `CreateFromRawString(string rawDataFromLog)` if it would be helpful, decide yourself

If you want more info please share code you are using for serialization/deserializaton

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So... would the 'Entry' class both describe the block and hold an array of data that is read? So another 'Parser' class could iterate through the 'Entry' classes, check what type of variable to read and store it in the array?

Comment: Ok.. so would you use a List for the data that is read? I guess that there is no typesafe way of doing this, since blocks can have datetime, float or int values?

Comment: So make IEntry<T> generic and property T BlockData

Comment: So.. a 'Field' class, which defines which type (int,float,byte), the descriptive name and the actual value, then a 'block' class which contains a list of 'Field' and the number to read, then a 'Log' class, which contains a list of 'block' and things like log name and identifying characteristics? Is it the 'field' which would be IEntry<T>? So then how can I have a list of IEntry<T>, if all the <T> are different? Is this possible?

Comment: If all of fields implements the same interface IField so T could be constrained as where T: IField

Comment: That makes sense.. thank you. So I think I now get how to describe the structure of the log file, but how would the data that is read from the file fit into such a scheme? I guess that 'log' would need to hold 300-odd copies of an 'entry' class, each containing the 'blocks', each containing the read data? But then the name and details for each of the fields is replicated 300 times? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: If name of Entry is unique you could use map IDictionary<string, IEntry>

Comment: Thanks for your continuing support! So would you store this separately, in the `log` class and just use the above structure to describe how it should be read? Or would you expect each `field` to contain one data value? From Bob's comment above, it would seem good to separate the storage of the data from the description of how it is stored, but then I may as well end up back at the DataTable approach again - all the additional classes etc seem to be unnecessary if this is the case?

Comment: Ok.. so I will look to describe the log file as explained above and then look to store the actual data in another format. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first start [here,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop) to learn a little bit about what object oriented programming is. Don't worry about your current problem while learning about OOP.

As you are learning about OO concepts, you should begin to understand code is not data, and data is not code. It does not matter how you represent your data from an OOP stance. You can write OO code to consume your data, or you could write procedurage code to consume your data, that part is irrelevant to the format of the data.

So then getting back to your question

> My question is how best to represent this data

It depends on your needs. What is writing the log file? Do you have control over the writer and reader? If I did I would rely on build the built in [serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) methods to minize the amount of code I need to write. Is the log file going to be really long? If so the "datatable" approach you described is usually better. If the log file isn't going to be a huge in file size, XML is really easy to work with.

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for the links. I have tried to read around the subject quite a bit - but it is just getting my head into the right way of thinking that I am struggling with! I am sure that this comes with experience, but at the moment it appears as though there are 100 ways to do this and I'm sure 100 more that I haven't even thought of yet. The log file is being generated in binary format elsewhere. I just need to decode and display it - but cannot change how it is structured. I thought that serialization adds extra info around the raw data - am I incorrect here? How would I go about this?

Comment: The advantages of having an OO solution for your problem would begin to show when you have multiple log file formats you need to consume. A base class would define the process for how to decode a file with all the common methods like opening a file, reading a ling, closing a file, returning the results for display etc. When you say the log file is `generated in binary format elsewhere` do you mean binary in the standard sense? Because if that is the case binary deserealization is the only option you really have.

Comment: By 'in binary format', I mean that if an entry starts with a date, the first six bytes could be 0x070b0a023125 (7 nov 2010, 02:49:37). When I try to serialize a class, it adds a lot of bulk around the actual data - could you please give an example of how you would go about this?

Answer (score 0):

As for OOP, you want to learn [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29).

I would suggest you build this using Test Driven Development.

Start small, with a simple fragment of your log data and write a test like (you'll find a better way to do this with experience and apply it to your situation):

```
[Test]
public void ReadSequence_FiveA_ReturnsProperList()
{
  // Arrange
    string sequenceStub = "AAAAA";

    // Act
    MyFileDecoder decoder = new MyFileDecoder();
    List<string> results = decoder.ReadSequence(sequenceStub);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(5, results.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual("A", results[0]);
}
```

That test code snippet is just a starting point, and I've tried to be rather verbose in the assertions.  You can come up with more creative ways over time.  The point is to start small.  Once this test passes, add another test where you mix "AB" and change your decoder to handle this properly.  Eventually, you'll have a large set of tests that handle your different formats.  Using TDD, you'll be on the path to using SOLID properly.  Whenever you find something you can't test, you should review the rules and see if you can't make it simpler and inject dependencies.

Eventually you'll get into mocking.  For example, you might find that you'd rather INJECT the ability for your `MyFileDecoder` class to have a dependency that will read your log file.  In that case, you would create a mock object and pass that into the constructor and set the mock to return the `sequenceStub` when a method is called.

Comment: Thank you. I have read a lot recently about C#/OOP/etc.. but had not come across SOLID before. I will give it a good read! Do you have any suggestions on how to address the data?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Bob has offered, I highly recommend [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) as a gentle, but robust introduction to OO for a C# programmer. The samples are in Java, which translate easily to C#.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently making my way through it! It is a great book - especially for a beginner like me, but I am still finding it hard to make the leap of logic to see how each may apply to my code.